# Redhat CGroup RAM usage file equivalents in Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, cpu-usage, cgroups, replit

I have a program that reads the following files:

```bash
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_period_us /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.soft_limit_in_bytes /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes &&grep '^\\(total_rss\\|total_cache\\) ' /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
```

On some Linux machines, it works fine. But I'm trying to make it cross-platform and I'm using Node.js. How can I get all of this info (RAM usage, CPU usage, etc) from Node **in the same format as the command above**?

So I basically want to know exactly what the files in the above command do, and how I can generate the same output using Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the usage using these two functions:

`os.freemem()`

Amount of free memory in bytes.

`os.totalmem()`

Total amount of memory in bytes.

Source: [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

Comment: I'm already using those functions, but how do I get the info in the same format as the command I sent?